# How to create a treeview using MVC3 and jquery and get the modified tree back server side?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I am pretty new to ASP .NET MVC3 and I can't seem to get my head around how to do this. I want to be able to take a Model of mine and create a treeview with it. This part is easy enough, I pass the model to my view and I loop over the list and I generate the HTML. Then I use one of these jquery plugins to render the HTML as a tree view.

The next part is what I am having trouble with. I want to be able to modify the treeview using whatever methods exposed by the jquery plugin. Once I am finished modifying, I want to be able to post back and have that data server side so that I can process it. How can I pass this data back to my controller?

Again, I am new to MVC so forgive me if I am missing something very obvious. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the piece you're missing is that you're trying to do it the 'chunky' way.

Post your changes edit-by-edit. Each move should be posted back, so you're recording operations. This is 'chatty', most site operate like this, with saves happening automagically for the user behind the scenes.

With this approach, you're not trying to parse out the entire tree and figure out what has changed. You're simply sending commands to the server like "CreateNode", "DeleteNode" or "MoveNode" and you can deal with the node in isolation.

As a tip, remember to attribute each of your nodes with an ID so that you can easily identify them via script.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I revised the logic to do as such.